# Complexity of cubic graph decomposition

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs

I am aware that deciding the existence of decomposition of a cubic graph into edge-disjoint claws is polynomial time solvable. Since a cubic graph has a decomposition into edge-disjoint claws if and only if it is bipartite.

> What is the complexity of deciding the existence of decomposition of a cubic graph into vertex disjoint claws? Is it NP-complete?

In the former problem, we partition the edge set into edge-disjoint claws while in the later one we partition the vertex set into vertex-disjoint claws.

Comment: [Egawa, Yoshimi, and Katsuhiro Ota. "Vertex-disjoint claws in graphs." Discrete mathematics 197 (1999): 225-246.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X99900699) is a related result, but doesn't seem to answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the problem is eqivalent to the [1-perfect code problem](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X94900264) in cubic graphs. Therefore, Deciding the existence of decomposition of a cubic graph into vertex disjoint claws is NP-complete.